# How to use LayoutView.getRegionManager

Tags: marionette

I want to remove all regions (add add new ones) in LayoutView.
`RegionManager.removeRegions()` is good, but while I can `layout.getRegionManager()`, it does not contain the regions `layout` has.

```
_.size(  layout.getRegions()                     )  // 1
_.size(  layout.getRegionManager().getRegions()  )  // 0
```

### Question: How to use `getRegionManager`?

---

Note: removing all regions can be done without `getRegionManager` as below, but using RM should be neater.

```
_.each(   _.keys(layout.regions),   function (rname) { layout.removeRegion(rname); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to use `getRegionManager`, but `layout.regionManager` can do what was intended:
`layout.regionManager.removeRegions` clears all regions in `layout`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Julian but `regionManager` does the thing that the author (me) wanted to do with `getRegionManager`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you'r the same -.- Maybe you can provide a bit more information and external resources to make the answer more something of an answer than a comment

Comment: Or delete the quedtion. It's not a programming related **problem**, but you not using the standard API correctly. And it might not help others